# Ruby on rails - set up a null foreign key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys, ruby-on-rails-5

How do I set a foreign key null? because I want to relate two tables, user and team, but it is not mandatory for a user to have a team.

`rails g scaffold Time name: string user: references`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's allowed to be null on db level. Within Time models add optional option, like - `belongs_to :user, optional: true`
Check related docs [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#optional)

Comment: just define `:optional` in the model team that rails will understand that the foreign key is not mandatory?

Comment: Yep (there is no foreign key not null constraint by default)

Answer (score 5):

**Rails level ( model validation )**

In Rails 4.x , when defining a references, the associated record for `belongs_to` is optional. From Rails 5.x, this association is required.

In Rails 4, to make associated record required, you will do

```
class Photo
  belongs_to :user, required: true
end
```

In Rails 5, to make associated record optional, you will do

```
class Photo
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

**DB level**

You need to make sure that your migration does not have constraint `null: false`. You should check migration to make sure it looks sth like below

```
create_table :photos do |t|
   t.references :user, null: true, foreign_key: true
end
```

Comment: Note if you run something like generate migration AddUserRefToProducts user:references. It will automatically create null:false. So you will need to update it in the migration. Further, as stated above,  optional: true on the belongs_to relation.

Answer (score 0):

When you're designing your tables it's not advisable to put data which is not related to the parent.

For example:
User can have multiple photos

```
user table
id name
```

```
photos table
id url user_id
```

if you're going to store photos without user_id then those photos will not be retrieved when you want to access photos of a particular user. That's why rails doesn't allow you to store records if you've defined a column as `references`.

you can refer the issue here [DHH github (rails)](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18233).

In the association add `optional: true` to achieve this functionality.